# slidify package not available in R 3.1.2?

Tags: r

I was trying to install Slidify package using R version 3.1.2 in Window OS.

using the command-
install.packages("slidify")

it returns an error saying 'slidify' is unavailable for version 3.1.2.

Is this really not available for version 3.1.2?

If so what is the alternate package that i can use instead of 'Slidify'?

Comment: note that Rstudio has built in presentation tool https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486468-Authoring-R-Presentations - it doesn't do all of what slidify does, and is baked into the rstudio IDE

Answer (score 7):

Slidify is not on CRAN (yet?). You have to install it from GitHUB (as mentioned on the Slidify website):

> Slidify is not on CRAN as yet and needs to be installed from github.
>   You can use Hadley's devtools package to accomplish this easily. You
>   will also need slidifyLibraries which contains all external libraries
>   required by Slidify.

```
library(devtools)
install_github('slidify', 'ramnathv')
install_github('slidifyLibraries', 'ramnathv')
```

Comment: I get a warning `Username parameter is deprecated. Please use ramnathv/slidify`, so I run `install_github('ramnathv/slidify')` and `install_github('ramnathv/slidifyLibraries')` instead.

Comment: It's a warning and things should work. You can also use the latter approach suggested therein. I just copy/pasted from the slidify github repo and wasn't paying much attention, sorry.